# See files on an ISO DVD without burning it to disc?

Tags: dvd, iso

I use daemon tools in Windows to see files in an ISO DVD image. Are there any tools like that on Ubuntu? How do I see the files in an ISO DVD image without burning it to disc?

Answer (score 5):

You can mount them in Gnome just by right clicking on them and clicking Archive Mounter.

[image]

Sometimes that doesn't work too well. If not:

```
sudo mount -oloop -tudf,iso9660 [isofile] [directory]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a directory to mount the ISO image.

For example, you could create the directory /mnt/myISOMount, mount the ISO to that directory, and explore the ISO files in that directory.

It would look something like this:

Create the directory:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/myISOMount
```

Mount the ISO:

```
sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 your_iso_file.iso /mnt/myISOMount
```

Change to the directory and explore the files in the ISO:

```
cd /mnt/myISOMount
```

Answer (score 0):

AcetoneISO can also be used to mount ISO files.